# Object.Equals return false

Tags: c#, oop, prototype, clone

Object.Equals always return false, Why not equal?

```
Student student = new Student(3, "Jack Poly");
Student otherStudent = (Student)student.Clone();
if (Object.Equals(student, otherStudent))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
else
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
 }
```

Clone method like below

```
    public override StudentPrototype Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone() as StudentPrototype;
    }
```

Comment: Because `Clone` returns two differences instances. Even if those instances have the same properties they are not equal, unless you override `Equals` appropriately.

Comment: You are doing deep cloning and object.equals compares address if the comparing items are reference types.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN

> If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method
>   tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object) method
>   is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method. Reference
>   equality means that the object variables that are compared refer to
>   the same object.

Your `Student` is a reference type, The clone `MemberwiseClone` returns a new other `object`.

```
Student student = new Student(3, "Jack Poly");
Student otherStudent = (Student)student.Clone();
```

So the `Equal` must return `false`

Answer (score 1):

When calling `Clone` you create a completely new instance of your class that has the same properties and fields as the original. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.icloneable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Creates **a new object** that is a copy of the current instance

Both instances are completely independent, even though they reference the exact same values on every single property or field. In particular changing properties from one doesn´t affect the other.

On the other hand `Equals` by default compares if two **references** are equal, which obviously is false in your case. In other words: only because you have two students named Marc doesn´t mean they are the same person. You have to implement what equality means, e.g. by comparing the sur-names or their students identity-number or a combination of those.

You can just override `Equals` in your `Student`-class:

```
class Student
{
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        var student = other as Student;
        if(student == null) return false;
        return this.Name == student.Name;
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
if (student.Equals(otherStudent)) ...
```

Comment: Your `Equals` example has a compiler warning that it hides the inherited `Object.Equals`. In other words, a correct implementation of `Equals` is a lot more complex than your example.